# How does electric flux being equal to zero imply electric field is zero?

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law

I've seen in a few places an argument used that when the flux is zero, the electric field is zero but I don't understand how implication is followed while I do understand that a zero electric field will generate no flux through any surface but how does zero flux imply no electric field?

As a simple counter-example, consider an electric dipole, any surface containing the electric dipole would have zero flux but still, the dipole generates some non zero amount of field!

I saw this argument being used [in this PSE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/419410/236734), [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/399660/236734) and [page-4 in these notes](https://www.phys.hawaii.edu/%7Emorse/P272fall10-6_pdf.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Zero flux does not imply zero field in general. What you are seeing being (perhaps implicitly) employed is the argument of spherical symmetry. For a spherically symmetric charge distribution (perhaps a point charge), the electric field on the Gaussian sphere sharing the same center as the charge distribution has the same magnitude and is in the radial direction at each point on the sphere. If the total charge enclosed is zero, coupled with Gauss' law, this implies zero field on the sphere.

Comment: Bit difficult to digest but if I understood correctly, having no charge inside a spherical volume implies spherical symmetrical symmetry for electric field? How did you conclude this?

Comment: No. The charge distribution needs to be spherically symmetric, like two concentric spherical shells containing equal and opposite charge. If the charge distribution is spherically symmetric, spherical symmetry requires that the electric field be radially outward or inward, i.e. perpendicular to the Gaussian sphere.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. The flux is the integral of **E**$\bullet$**dS** where **E** is the electric field at a surface element **dS**. If the flux = 0, that just means that this integral is 0. We can't say anything more about the electric field unless there is some symmetry present. For instance, if we have a charge q and an equal and opposite charge -q located at the center of a spherical surface, by Gauss' Law the net flux through the surface is 0. But we know that the electric field due to each charge is constant on the surface so the flux integral can be calculated as (E(q) + E(-q))4$\pi$$R^2$ where R is the radius of the surface. This implies that the net field is 0.

Now let's consider a point charge right outside of a spherical surface, S. Since the charge is outside S, by Gauss' Law we know the flux through S due to the charge is 0. The electric field on S will not be spherically symmetric due to the location of the charge, so we can't separate it out and say it's 0. In fact, it is not 0. Locations on the surface close to the charge will experience a relatively strong field and locations at the opposite end will experience a relatively weaker field. The net flux through the surface is 0 but the electric field on the surface is not 0.